# What are the ways of developing Android Applications in Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

There doesn't seems to be a clear explanation whether running a Linux Desktop Environment is allowed in Google Cloud Shell or not.
Thus, developing Android Applications doesn't seems to be an easy task.

A few options seem possible :

• Can a desktop environment be run on Google Cloud Shell and connected using some remote desktop software such as Chrome Remote Desktop ? This will enable to install Android Studio in Google Cloud Shell.

• Can it be connected to VSCode on local desktop so that Flutter applications can be developed ? If yes, then please share the steps to do it.

• Is there any way of running Gitpod like Remote instance on Cloud Shell but without local client (Jetbrains Space) like rendering the instance on browser except using the abandoned project Jetbrains Projector ? Means is there an alternative of Jetbrains Projector that is still supported and actively developed ?

If any other valid solution is available please share the solutions and steps of the same. If there's any other free (without requiring billing account) solution other than Google Cloud Shell then also please share.

Comment: You are not looking at the right tool. Have a look to Cloud Workstation (more expensive, but compliant with your requirement!)

Comment: When using the shell to write Android applications, you're literally shooting yourself into the foot, since the tools available there are `nano` and `gradle`. Don't expect any GUI in a shell. Why not just install Android Studio instead of that questionable VS.Code?